# Winrt c# - bug event Holding execute double time

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-runtime, gesture, touch-event

I come to you today because of a bug with the event : Holding. I have a canvas with on it an image. I want to add something at the holding position. After a time, the event add my "pin" but when I stopped the holding he did a second time the holding event.
If I make a another gesture he didn't do a second time the holding event, but this is not a solution..
If anybody has an idea ? This is the "basic" code :

```
private void Image_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition(Image);

        PlacePoint(position.X, position.Y);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Holding events come in pairs:

```
Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Started
```

and one of

```
Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Canceled

Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Completed
```

So, consider putting something like this at the start of your method:

```
if (e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Started || e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Canceled ) return;
```